# Can we use constructor functions in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Can we use constructor functions in TypeScript without converting them to classes? I'm guessing we have to declare the value of `this` here:

```js
function Car() {
    this.name = 'first'; // 'this' implicitly has type 'any'...
}
```

Comment: The question is, why do you want to? Constructor functions are obsolete. If you need to target very old browsers, write classes and set the target to ES3; the compiler will convert your classes to constructor functions.

Comment: You can explicitely type it as a parameter to the function https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function

Comment: Yeah, the question is not very practical - just curiosity. But yes, the first link answers my questions. Thanks!